# what can only be done by setTimeout not by setInterval in javascript

Tags: javascript

**I want to know something that can only be done by setTimeout not by setInterval in javascript.**

-do not want to know the differences in both of them
- there should be something which can only be done by setTimeout not by setInterval

Comment: You do not want to know the differences but you want to know the different uses... Explain to me

Comment: Any task for once without using clearTimeout/clearInterval.

Comment: In case you want to repeat a task after an exact period since the task is complete, where the duration to process the task is larger than the mentioned period, calling setTimeout() recursively is better suitable than setInterval()

Answer (score 1):

If you understand the difference you understand the different uses. Read through this answer: [setTimeout or setInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval?rq=1) this should explain it

Comment: Not exactly. Here question is different.

Answer (score 0):

As i posted a comment:

`setTimeout()` would run for once in the given delay while `setInterval()` would run continuously for the interval delay.

So, essentially `setTimeout()` you can use if you just want to execute a specific task once in a given delay.

A test is below:

```js
setTimeout(()=>console.log('setTimeout:::'), 2000); // logs once
setTimeout(()=>console.log('------------------------'), 2000);
setInterval(()=>console.log('setInterval:::'), 2000); // logs each 2sec
```

Yet there are other ways to achieve things in vice-versa between these two.

Comment: asking something that can only be done by setTimeout can not by setInterval.

Comment: I also mentioned _Any task run for once._

Comment: which can also done by setInterval and then u can clear that interval

Comment: Boss this was not in the question and plz read the last line in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to  run codes in some time and these code are only runned once,you can use `setTimeout`.

eg:

1   I need to run `alert('setTimeout')`  after 1s  when the page is loaded

`window.onload=  function(){
    setTimeout(function(){alert('setTimeout')},1000);
}`

2. I need to run `alert('setInterval')` per 1s when the page is loaded

`window.onload=  function(){
    setInterval(function(){alert('setInterval')},1000);
}`